# Upgrade 16.04 openvz to 18.04 but keep kernel to 2.6

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, do-release-upgrade, openvz

Since OpenVZ cannot be upgraded from inside of the VM's client (which I only rent). Is it possible to upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 16.04.5 LTS?

The problem lies on libc/locales

`This version of libc requires kernel version 3.2 or later. Plase upgrade your kernel before installing glibc`

tried to `apt-mark hold libc6` and `locales`, the `do-release-upgrade` refuses to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the OpenVZ 6 kernel on the host doesn't support Ubuntu 18.04.  You need to wait for an update for the OpenVZ 6 kernel, or move to another host using OpenVZ 7 or Virtuozzo 7.